# What is the point of ls -f (or, why is this hanging?)

Tags: linux, ls, gnu, coreutils

I've got a directory with about 100,000 files in it.  ls -f hangs for over a minute.  I ran strace, and immediately started seeing getdents, so ls is clearly reading the directory.  I also see a lot of calls to brk, so ls is clearly buffering things in memory.  I wrote a simple program that calls readdir and outputs filenames, and it responds immediately.  But ls -f does not provide output.  What gives?  I thought the whole point of -f is that it causes ls to do nothing more than readdir.  Is there a portable, reliable way to list the contents of a directory?  (Note, this is ls from gnu's coreutils on Linux.)

-EDIT-

There was an alias in place, but "/bin/ls -1f > /dev/null" takes 8 to 15 seconds, "/bin/ls -1fx > /dev/null" takes 4 to 11 seconds, but a simple program that just does readdir takes .011 seconds.  What do I need to do to make gnu ls not suck?

Answer (score 7):

The point of `-f` is to try and avoid the need to stat every file entry, and to avoid the need to read them all before any are displayed.  It is a "meta" option that just disables other options.

So, yes, it should do what you expect.  I can't answer why it isn't, but I would guess that you might have a shell alias or something else that inserts additional options to the command.  That might reenable a feature than `-f` disables, and be considered "more specific", so take precedence.

Comment: Argghh.  ls() { /bin/ls -FB $@; }  Stupid startup scripts.

Comment: hmm.  I unset the function and I still see the same behavior even when I run /bin/ls.

Comment: Do /bin/ls -f -1  (that's minus-one, not minus-ell).  The /bin/ls on a RHEL box I'm using formats file names in columns for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

An optimization was added in coreutils 7.0 (commit 8d974b00fbbc2025de63e1e6d54827648fefa1c4):

```
2008-08-01  Kamil Dudka  <kdudka@redhat.com>
    ls -U1 now uses constant memory
    When printing one name per line and not sorting, ls now uses
    constant memory per directory, no matter how many files are in
    the directory.
    * ls.c (print_dir): Print each file name immediately, when possible.
    * NEWS: Mention the improvement.
```

The first explanation that comes to mind is that you're running an older version of coreutils. You need to upgrade.